# Clarification on the existence of integrals and notation

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Consider the random variable $X: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^l$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with image $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$.

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^l, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^l))$ where $ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^l)$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^l$.

Consider a function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that we are said that $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t)d\mu$ is **well defined**, where $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^l, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^l))$ [when $\mu$ is a probability measure then $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t)d\mu=\mathbb{E}(f(X))$].

I'm confused about the words **well defined**.

---

When $l=1$ and $\mathcal{X}=[a,b]$, the integral $\int_{[a,b]}f(t) dt$ exists (i.e. is well-defined) when

(i)$f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$

(ii) $\sup_PL_f(P)$ exists, where $L_f(P)$ is the Lower Riemann sum and P is a partition of $[a,b]$

(iii) $\inf_p U_f(P)$ exists, where  $U_f(P)$ is the Upper Riemann sum and P is a partition of $[a,b]$

(iv) $\sup_PL_f(P)=\inf_p U_f(P)$

If I have understood correctly, just by writing down $\int_{[a,b]}f(t) dt$ it means that $\int_{[a,b]}f(t) dt$ is well-defined and, hence, $-\infty< \int_{[a,b]}f(t) dt<\infty$.

I guess we can generalise this definition to $l>1$ and $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$.

---

> Question: Is there something similar for $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) d\mu$? What
>    does it mean that $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) d\mu$ is well-defined (i.e.
>    exists)? Does it imply that $-\infty<\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t)
> d\mu<\infty$? And, is there any relation between the existence of
>    $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) dt$ and  $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) d\mu$?

My intuition is that, differently from case (1), writing down $\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) d\mu$ does not mean that $-\infty<\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t) d\mu<\infty$, otherwise it wouldn't make sense assuming $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ (when $\mu$ is a probability measure) as I have seen doing in many proofs. Could you clarify these points? I'm really confused. Any hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, we do not restrict the integral to be finite. If $f = f^+ - f^-$, where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$, we could require $f^- < \infty$ or $f^+ < \infty$ in order to define $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$ without ambiguity (only one of the two parts need be finite, and in the case where one is finite the integral still exists while having value $\pm \infty$).

Comment: I am not sure in the context, but $\int fd\mu$ well defined could mean that at most one of the integrals $\int f^+d\mu$ and $\int f^-d\mu$ takes value $+\infty$. These integrals have nonnegative integrands.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^l, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^l))$. Hence $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(t)d\mu=\int_{\mathcal{X}}tf_X(t)dt$ when $X$ is continuous and $f_X$ is the probability density function. If you look the definition of expected value of a continuous random variable here http://www.statlect.com/expval1.htm, it says "provided that $\int |t|f_X(t) dt<\infty$". Doesn't this mean that by definition $-\infty< \mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$?

Comment: The [definition  on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition)  allows expectations to take infinite values, though.

Comment: Ok, I see now. The wikipedia definition makes more sense. Thanks a lot